# HTML select element doesn't dropdown on top of THREE.js scene

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, three.js

I am on a project that extends Three.js editor.

[editor link](https://threejs.org/editor/)

I am trying to add a select element on top of viewport of editor. However dropdown of select element doesn't work.

I've tried different styles and attributes however no matter what I did, I couldn't figure it out. Because if I put html code of select element to js fiddle, it works.

Here is working select element on a clean html file.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umurcg/2c2fvv4s/2/)

Here is how I implement code in editor.
I put this code in the Viewport.js file of editor.

```
//...
var container = new UI.Panel();
container.setId( 'viewport' );
container.setPosition( 'absolute' );

//Here I am trying to add select element with using Mr.Doobs UI module

container.add(new UI.Row().add(new UI.Select().setOptions(["option1","option2"])));

//Here I am trying to add select element with pure javascript.
var parentDom=container.dom;

// subBut.addElement(new UI.Row().add(new UI.Text("HELOOOOOOO")));
var dom = document.createElement( 'select' );
dom.style.paddingLeft  = '80px';
dom.style.position="absolute";
dom.style.zIndex="999";

//For validating click event
dom.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("clicked");
})

for ( var i=0;i<5;i++ ) {

    var option = document.createElement( 'option' );

    option.value = i;
    option.innerHTML = "element";
    dom.appendChild( option );

}
dom.value = 4;
parentDom.appendChild(dom);



container.add( new Viewport.Info( editor ) );
```

I think it is related to three.js z-index but I am not sure. If you put the code in the Viewport.js you can replicate the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with **OrbitControls**, if you don't set an element to it, it will bind to the entire window, so dragging events will be also binded to your cursor.

A simple fix is just set the controls to a DOM element (your canvas that rendrers 3js)

```
let  container = document.getElementById( 'container' ); // Your actual DOM element
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement ); // Here is the magic
```